# Error parsing file: file.g3db, while using blender objects in libgdx

Tags: 3d, libgdx, blender, fbx

I was playing around with libGDX importing 3d models. I converted the fbx file to d3db successfully. This is the complete error and below is the  source code used in `show` method. I got the code from a tutorial and it should worked fine. Is there some problem with converter?

```
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mygdx.cube.android, PID: 19468
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: convertedModel.g3db
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:56)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.parseModel(G3dModelLoader.java:65)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.loadModelData(G3dModelLoader.java:61)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:53)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:69)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mygdx.cube.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:47)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mygdx.cube.Cube.create(Cube.java:9)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: convertedModel.g3db (Internal)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:151)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:54)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.parseModel(G3dModelLoader.java:65) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.loadModelData(G3dModelLoader.java:61) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:53) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:69) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mygdx.cube.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:47) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mygdx.cube.Cube.create(Cube.java:9) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: convertedModel.g3db
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:151) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:54) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.parseModel(G3dModelLoader.java:65) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.loadModelData(G3dModelLoader.java:61) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:53) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:69) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mygdx.cube.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:47) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mygdx.cube.Cube.create(Cube.java:9) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511) 
12-20 10:47:38.866 19468-19519/com.mygdx.cube.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239) 









public void show() {
            camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            camera.position.set(3.8f, 8f, 3f);


            camera.lookAt(0f,0f,0f);
            camera.near =0.1f;
            camera.far = 300f;

            modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

            UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();

            G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
            model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("convertedModel.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));

            modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);

            environment = new Environment();
            environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight,0.8f,0.8f,0.8f,1.0f));



            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a pretty straightforward error message: "FileNotFoundException: convertedModel.g3db". Make sure that the file name (case sensitive) is correct and that the file exists. To verify it, you can add the following code to the top of your `show()` method.

```
Gdx.app.log("", Gdx.files.internal("convertedModel.g3db").exists() ? "exists" : "does not exist");
```

Make sure that the filename is consistent in both lines (this line and the call to `loadModel`).

By default, internal files should be located in the `assets` sub folder of your android project or, when you dont have an android project, in the core project. This is the location where `badlogic.jpg` is located when you create a new project using the setup utility.

See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Comment: The file was manually put into android/assets directory. After putting it also in the android/assets in the Android studio it worked. Not sure why..I thought that it doesn't make a difference if a put it through android studio or through file sysem of an operating system